# rails app with multiple types of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns, database-design, web-applications

I am working on a ruby on rails application with many types of users. All users will share the basic properties of email address and password, along with the timestamp fields for created_at and updated_at. Other fields will be unique to the type of user (think Employee, Vendor, Manager, etc.) I have been looking into Single-Table Inheritance but that does not seem like the right pattern for this. The other option seems to be to have a User model that has_one of the other models. It is also possible for a User to have multiple types, ie. Employee and Manager could be the same User. I also want to direct the user to a specific page on login, based on what type of user they are. Would this be best done through constraints in the router or a large switch statement on login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to define user roles. I suggest [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to manage your roles and access privileges.

One way to to implement different fields on a single table would be to use NoSQL (hstore) from Postgres. This is a simple [introductory tutorial](http://schneems.com/post/19298469372/you-got-nosql-in-my-postgres-using-hstore-in-rails).

[Here](http://blog.rawonrails.com/2012/02/using-activerecordstore-with-rails-32.html) is and example of using it with Rails 3.2+